# Admob Sensitive Categories and Settings for All Age Groups

Tags: admob

I have a mobile application that doesn't require age restrictions. That's why I chose all age groups as the target audience. However, the ads are expected to be suitable for children.

Which sensitive categories should I block in Admob?

Categories : https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3150953?hl=en

I'm not sure if these should be added to the code. If added to the code, will the ad content only show ads for kids?

- maxAdContentRating
- tagForChildDirectedTreatment

My target audience is not just children, but all age groups. What do you think I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Details from - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjRY--FCnTk&ab_channel=DzianisIndieDeveloper

The target age group for Ants is: 9-12 and 13-15.
I blocked these categories.
1.Black Magic, Astrology & Esoteric
2.Cosmetic Procedures & Body Modification
help_outline
3.Dating
4.Drugs & Supplements
5.References to Sex & Sexuality
6.Sexual & Reproductive Health
7.Significant Skin Exposure
8.Social Casino Games
All other categories are available for ads.
Google Admob Settings for Children. Please choose Sensitive Categories and exclude these 8 categories.